# So there are 2 date columns in a table In sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table , with date format in YYYY-MM-DD.

| Acc_No | On_board_date | Arrival_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-02-04 |
| 002 | 2022-03-10 | 2022-03-07 |
| 003 | 2022-03-12 | 2022-03-25 |

What I want is Acc_No's whose arrival date is +/- 5 days from on_board_date
which will result in like these

| Acc_No | On_board_date | Arrival_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-02-04 |
| 002 | 2022-03-10 | 2022-03-07 |

This is what I have tried

```
select * from table
where on_board_date <= dateadd(arrival_date,5)
or on_board_date <= datesub(arrival_date,5)
```

Not getting desired result with this

Comment: `or on_board_date <= datesub(arrival_date,5)` - shouldn't that be `and`  and `>=`?

Comment: (Imagine an on_board_date which is much earlier than the arrival_date... that would still match your second condition at the moment, so it would be included...)

Comment: As a side note, "Not getting desired result" really doesn't tell us much. If you go to the doctor, you don't just say "I'm not well" and expect a diagnosis from that - you need to provide more information. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: ```WHERE DATEDIFF(On_board_date, Arrival_date) BETWEEN -5 AND 5```

Comment: Imagine the arrival date is 10, then you need an onboard date between 5 and 15. That's >= 5 AND <= 15 *(Though I suggest you use >= 5 AND < 15, search the Web about exclusive vs inclusive date ranges)*. But you have <= 15 OR <= 5...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the one Akina suggested

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(On_board_date, Arrival_date) BETWEEN -5 AND 5
```

This worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
select * from table
where on_board_date <= arrival_date + INTERVAL '5' day
```

Comment: Or the OP expected result doesn't match with the requirement